# Access file locally?

Tags: javascript, public-key-encryption

I create a online system (HTML+Javascript+PHP) where users can encrypt and decrypt messages, using opengpg.js.

I don't want to store the private key on the server. Do you know if it's possible in any way to store data on the local machine? So that the HTML page can access the file and get the key?

About 15 people will use the site, so I can myself configure the clients if it's needed.

For example - but this doesn't work:

**HTML Page (on Internet):**

```
<script src="file:///Users/kristoffer/Documents/key.js"></script>
<script>yourkey = key;</script>
```

**Local file (key.js)**

```
key = "the-private-key";
```

Comment: Why do you need a file? Can't you store your key into local storage (http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use the script tag to reference a local file on the browser, that's a security breach.

You can use cookies or [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to store the keys. Though both are horrible ideas in my opinion. You seem to imply this is a small local app on your intranet, so using local storage maybe ok in this case, but I want to make sure anybody else reading this answer understands that this is not a good day to do this.

Comment: a private key is called private for a reason :) you should store it on the server and take steps to secure it.